# How to write a query that calculates a value using a previous records value?

Tags: linq-to-sql, sql-server-ce

I'm trying to figure out the best way to calculate a value that is based on the *previous* records values. I'm sure it's possible, I just can't figure it out.

Consider a table that has `StartTime` & `EndTime`. Along with these values is are 2 different types of wages: `OnDuty` & `OffDuty`.

> **OnDuty** =  All time between `StartTime` and `EndTime`.
>
> **OffDuty**: All time between the *previous* `EndTime` and the *current* `StartTime`.

So to calculate `OffDuty`, we have to take the `EndTime` of the last record and subtract the `StartTime` of the current record.

### Example:

- OnDuty Wage = $10/hr
- OffDuty Wage = $2/hr

**Entry 1:**

```
StartTime: 1/1/2010 @ 8:00 AM
EndTime: 1/1/2010 @ 6:00 PM
Pay = $100 (10 hrs @ $10/hr)
```

**Entry 2:**

```
StartTime: 1/2/2010 @ 8:00 AM
EndTime: 1/2/2010 @ 6:00 PM
Pay = $128 (10 hrs @ $10/hr) + (14 hrs @ $2/hr)
```

**Entry 3:**

```
StartTime: 1/3/2010 @ 8:00 AM
EndTime: 1/3/2010 @ 10:00 AM
Pay = $48 (2 hrs @ $10/hr) + (14 hrs @ $2/hr)
```

Do you see the pattern?

```
Total Pay = $276 (Entry1.Pay + Entry2.Pay + Entry3.Pay)
```

Basically, I'm debating as to whether it would be best to:

1. put all of the burden on the database to calculate this value for each detail row, or
2. store the previous record's EndTime with each row (ie. PreviousEndTime?)

I like option 1 better. However, I don't even know how to approach this in terms of ***HOW*** to do this without creating a lookup query first (note: I'm using SqlCE). I'm relying heavily on LinqToSql and I'm concerned with performance using Linq, as there could be hundreds of thousands of these "Entry" records that need calculated to provide a singe `TotalPay` for each employee. To perform that lookup on each detail row would be painful!

On the flip side, I feel that there would be a lot of maintenance involved with using the 'PreviousEndTime' field approach. The user could go back and change the `EndTime` and the idea of updating the *next* record's `PreviousEndTime` sounds like a hack to me...

Thoughts? Ideas? Solutions? :)

Comment: which DB? if you have analytic functions you get PREVIOUS and other goodies.

Comment: "note: I'm using SqlCE" >> Unfortunately, SqlCE doesn't support these functions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ANSWER:** Just to update everybody on this, I resorted to a different approach...

Since I'm using SQL CE and it doesn't support Views or the Lead / Lag functions, I decided to add a new `PreviousEndTime` column to my table. This was the only elegant way that I could find that allowed me to easily query for a grand total calculation on an `Employee`. It is not my preferred solution, but it is working ok for me...

The only draw back with this approach is that when a user updates their `EndTime` on any record, I have to do a quick lookup to find the *next* record and update the `PreviousEndTime` value to ensure that my calculations return the correct values when querying.

Here is a quick pseudo code snippet of what I'm now doing:

```
public decimal GetTotalPay(Employee employee) {
   return (from row in _timeSheet.GetDetailRows(employee.Id)
      select ((row.StartTime - row.PreviousEndTime) * employee.OffDutyWage) +
             ((row.EndTime - row.StartTime) * employee.OnDutyWage)).Sum();
}
```

Thanks for all the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend the option to "put all of the burden on the database to calculate this value for each detail row". **This is the stuff databases (and their query languages) are made for.**

In Oracle you would use LEAD and LAG.

http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/LagLeadAnalyticFunctions.php

In SQL Server, there may be some workarounds, see for example:

http://www.rafael-salas.com/2008/05/t-sql-lead-and-lag-functions.html

Not sure if this is supported in SQL Server CE, though.

Comment: I agree that the DB is made for this. My concern is that my approach with LinqToSql might make it a costly routine to self reference sibling rows for each row. I should probably do some benchmarks to see if this is the case. Thanks for the response, though! It pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to store the previous row's end time. You can calculate differences with previous rows using the [Row_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) ranking function and then performing a self-join.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't think that SqlCE supports the Row_Number() function. I may have to approach my design from a different angle, or move the logic into the app instead. Thanks again.